# I am trying to see httpurlconnection for one of the webpage

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, httpurlconnection

while trying to check the broken links in selenium for one of the webpage i am not able to get the response message. i get the below error.

Can you please help me out what is the problem
Code used is  :

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(activelinks.get(j).getAttribute("href")).openConnection();
connection.connect();
Serializable response = connection.getResponseMessage();
connection.disconnect();
System.out.println(activelinks.get(j).getAttribute("href")+"----->"+response);
```

Error is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseMessage(Unknown Source)
    at Testng.amazonn.amazontestcase.main(amazontestcase.java:45)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to extract the response you may like to set a definite *connection Timeout* and check the response in a `if()` loop before closing the connection as follows :

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(activelinks.get(j).getAttribute("href")).openConnection();
connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
connection.connect();
if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) 
{
    System.out.println(activelinks.get(j).getAttribute("href")+"----->" + connection.getResponseMessage());
}

if (connection.getResponseCode() == httpUrlConnect.HTTP_NOT_FOUND) 
{
    System.out.println(activelinks.get(j).getAttribute("href")+"----->" + connection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
}
```